# Compass interferences when GPS is working on Android

Tags: android, filter, gps, compass-geolocation

I'm making an application for Android which uses a MapView thats rotates according to the compass data.

The problem is that when GPS sensor is working (to locate my position and translate it into the MapView), compass data gets so much interferences. And if I turn it off, compass works well again.

I'm using a low-pass filter, but interferences are bigger than 90º, so it doesn't work.

Any solution?

Here is my GPS class code:

```
public class LocationController implements LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener {

private static final String TAG = "LOOKAROUND_LOCATION";

private LocationManager mService;
private LocationProvider mProvider;
private GpsStatus mStatus;
private ArrayList<LocationActivity> mLocationActivities = new ArrayList<LocationActivity>();
boolean mStarted;
private Location mLastLocation;

private static LocationController sInstance;

public static LocationController getInstance(Context context) {
    if(sInstance == null){
        sInstance = new LocationController(context);
    }
    return sInstance;
}

public void addLocationActivity(LocationActivity activity) {
    mLocationActivities.add(activity);
}

public LocationController(Context context){
    mService = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mProvider = mService.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (mProvider == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to get GPS_PROVIDER");
    }
    mService.addGpsStatusListener(this);
}

public void gpsStart() {
    if (!mStarted) {
        mService.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider.getName(), 1000, 0.0f, this);
        mStarted = true;
    }
    for (LocationActivity activity : mLocationActivities) {
        activity.gpsStart();
    }
}

public void gpsStop() {
    if (mStarted) {
        mService.removeUpdates(this);
        mStarted = false;
    }
    for (LocationActivity activity : mLocationActivities) {
        activity.gpsStop();
    }
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;

    for (LocationActivity activity : mLocationActivities) {
        activity.onLocationChanged(location);
    }
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    for (LocationActivity activity : mLocationActivities) {
        activity.onProviderDisabled(provider);
    }
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    for (LocationActivity activity : mLocationActivities) {
        activity.onProviderEnabled(provider);
    }
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    for (LocationActivity activity : mLocationActivities) {
        activity.onStatusChanged(provider, status, extras);
    }

}

public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
     mStatus = mService.getGpsStatus(mStatus);
        for (LocationActivity activity : mLocationActivities) {
            activity.onGpsStatusChanged(event, mStatus);
        }

}

public void shutdownGps(){
    mService.removeGpsStatusListener(this);
    mService.removeUpdates(this);
}

public float getAccuracy(){
    float acc = -1;
    if(mLastLocation != null){
        acc = mLastLocation.getAccuracy();
    }
    return acc;
}

public float getDeclination(){
    float declination = 0;
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField(
                (float) mLastLocation.getLatitude(),
                (float) mLastLocation.getLongitude(),
                (float) mLastLocation.getAltitude(),
                mLastLocation.getTime());
        declination = geoField.getDeclination();
    }
    return declination;
}
```

}

And this is the Orientation class code:

```
public class OrientationController implements SensorEventListener{
private static final String TAG = "LOOKAROUND_ORIENTATION";
static final float ALPHA = 0.2f;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private ArrayList<OrientationActivity> mOrientationActivities = new ArrayList<OrientationActivity>();
Sensor accelerometer;
Sensor magnetometer;
float[] mGravity = null;
float[] mGeomagnetic = null;
float azimut;

private static OrientationController sInstance;

public static OrientationController getInstance(Context ctx) {
    if (sInstance == null)
        sInstance = new OrientationController(ctx);
    return sInstance;
}

public void addOrientationActivity(OrientationActivity activity) {
    mOrientationActivities.add(activity);
}

private OrientationController(Context ctx) {
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private float[] lowPass( float[] input, float[] output ) {
    if ( output == null ) return input;
    for ( int i=0; i<input.length; i++ ) {
        output[i] = output[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - output[i]);
    }
    return output;
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            mGravity = lowPass(event.values, mGravity);
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            mGeomagnetic = lowPass(event.values, mGeomagnetic);
    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity,
                mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            azimut = orientation[0];
            float degAzimut = (float)Math.toDegrees(azimut);
            for(OrientationActivity orientationActivity : mOrientationActivities){
                orientationActivity.onOrientationChanged(degAzimut);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I've never saw any interference from GPS in compass. Better to post your code related to GPS, as the problem should be something else.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use the bearing from the gps instead of the compass.  This only works well of course if your user is moving and is what I do with my cyceling app.  If your user is not moving then maybe get a gps fix and then switch it off and go back to compass.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've been working on this and now I noticed that if I use the deprecated Orientation Sensor instead of the API recommended combination of Accelerometer and Magnetic Field sensors, my app works good and smooth.

So the question now is why deprecated method is working better than the newest one? Am I doing something wrong?